# Windows Phone 8.1 Cordova scroll

Tags: css, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, touch

I have Jquery Mobile, Cordova project. Everything seems to work fine on iOS and Android.

Windows Mobile 8.1 does not scroll the content after the app is created. The scroll happens after touchends. So that when you swipe the finger and lift it, only after that the page scrolls, not during the swipe.

I have some swipe actions assigned to some elements, tried to disable them but no joy.

I've tried to rebuild, I don't have any touch disabling css and on IE browser everything works just fine.

Any ideas how I can debug or find what's wrong?

Comment: Are you aware of the [touch-action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx) property?

Comment: Thanks, balzafin. I am and that is not helping. I tried atleast with pan-y and scroll to body...
I believe that the matter is more about Cordova, cause it works with IE.

Comment: Ok. I had the same issue with wp8 (jQM 1.4.5+PhoneGap 1.6.3) and I'm quite sure the fix had something to do with touch-action. Can't remember if there was more to it, but this is how I have it right now: `html {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
    touch-action: pan-x;
}
body {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -ms-content-zooming: none;
}` Also fixed the viewport size like this: `@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 @-ms-viewport {
    width: 320px;
    user-zoom: fixed;
    max-zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
 }
}body, html { 
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important; 
}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Unfortunately there was no effect on repairing this issue. I do think that if it had something to do with the css then the content would not scroll at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was pretty simple to find.

I had in the config.xml set:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

Took it out and everything worked fine. Again, this is only for Windows Phone 8.

I'm running Cordova 4.3.0.

Thanks again balzafin!